# Azure Cloud Director not working after clicking 'OK' - No error message, nothing else

Tags: azure, cloud

Now I want to try this program (link: http://www.cogno-sys.com/azure-cloud-management/azure-cloud-director-single-click-azure-deployment/ ) because I have some problem to deploy my app to Azure.
So I downloaded it and it requires first to add a subscription ID. But after I fill all field I click the button OK but nothing happening...(I added the certification path and password, too) No error message, nothing else. This pop-up window is on the screen still
(the problem is the same when I ad the Certhumprint and then clikc to Check, but nothing again. If I click the OK button now the error messages show to click to check button first)

Are you using this? Do you have the same problem with it?

Comment: This sounds like a customer support question for CognoSys, not a Windows Azure question.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it and I found you really need to fill all the fields in the "Add Subscription" dialog. As you are already a Windows Azure user, you may already have a self signed certificate installed in your desktop and exported its PFX and CER in which CER is uploaded to Azure Management Portal.

If you have above setup ready try again "Add Subscription" option in  "Cloud Director" and in "Add Subscription" dialog:

1. First Click "Certificate Thumbprint" option and include the ThumbID of the certificate which is uploaded to Azure Management Portal and then press "Check" button. The Thumb ID color will change from  red to green mean it is validated.
2. Now Click on "Local PFX File" option and select the PFX file using "..." button and enter the PFX password in the "Password" text box.

After you fill all 3 certificate related input field, press "OK" and you will see progress bar active.

If "Cloud Director" team can read this, please this process more intuitive and easy.

Comment: Thank you your reply. As David Makogon said I submitted a support ticket to CognoSys and they answered it but I dont want to post it out due to its lenght... But I will try all of your offer

Answer (score 0):

there is a setup wizard when you login first time. it should guide you to setup account. initially there was a manual entry form for subscription which has been replaced with setup wizard which should properly guide you.

Incase you are unable to get same, go to Help or application menu and choose "Reset Data" and it shall restart with the wizard and clear all local data.

Raise support ticket if you need help still.